# Change System.in and make Scanners use one ByteArrayInputStream?

Tags: java, testing, junit, user-input

I am tasked with writing a test program to assess whether a student's homework works or not. 
The students are writing a Rock, Paper, Scissors game in Java and turning in single class that plays through a game with n rounds by asking the user for input in the command line.
All of these students will be using one or more Scanner objects to read input off of the console, so I need to make my test program simulate some predetermined inputs and check for expected outputs. 
I override System.in, so when a student calls `Scanner myReader = new Scanner(System.in);`, I get to dictate what the input is (using ByteArrayInputStream).
To get an idea of how I've started:

```
public class TestRockPaperScissors extends RockPaperScissors{
public static void main(String[] args){
    InputStream stdin = System.in;
    try {
    System.setIn(new ByteArrayInputStream("<test inputs here>".getBytes()));
    RockPaperScissors.main(null); // This will be student code in another file.
    } finally {
        System.setIn(stdin);
    }

}
```

Problem is, this only works when the student only creates a single Scanner using System.in. Otherwise, I get errors, because there is no input present for the second Scanner to use .next() on.

TL;DR... How do I simulate console input for an arbitrary number of Scanners, given that I cannot see the source of the RockPaperScissors.main(null) call?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a clearer test for the command line interface by using the `StandardOutputStreamLog` and `TextFromStandardInputStream` rules of the [System Rules](http://stefanbirkner.github.com/system-rules/) library.

```
public class RockPaperScissorsTest() {
  @Rule
  public StandardOutputStreamLog log = new StandardOutputStreamLog();

  @Rule
  public TextFromStandardInputStream systemInMock = emptyStandardInputStream();

  @Test
  public void test1() {
    systemInMock.provideText("<test input>");
    RockPaperScissors.main(null);
    assertTrue(log.getLog().contains("<expected output>"));
  }

  @Test
  public void test2() {
    systemInMock.provideText("<another test input>");
    RockPaperScissors.main(null);
    assertTrue(log.getLog().contains("<expected output>"));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ask the students to write an object that runs RockPaperScissors by getting values from an InputStream, and writing results to a PrintStream, i.e. to write an implementation of the following interface

```
public interface RockPaperScissors {
    void runGame(InputStream in, PrintStream out) throws IOException;
}
```

That will allow them to test their own program using an instance of their class taking System.in and System.out as argument.

And that will allow you to unit test their program by passing your own ByteArrayInputStream containing the sequence of inputs, and your own ByteArrayOutputStream containing the output generated by the program, that you'll also be able to verify.

BTW, shouldn't the students learn to unit test their own code?

Comment: The students aren't writing their own test cases because this is Programming 101 at my University. These kids hadn't written a line of code until about 4 weeks ago. I agree in general though, they should have to write their own - make my job easier!
As a result of their 'freshness', they do not know how to use interfaces yet. So I am out of luck on that front.