# how to test the BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))

Tags: java, junit, junit4

My method:

```
public class CalcService {

    double inputA = 0.0;

    @SneakyThrows
    public void firstNumber() {
       System.out.println("Input first number");
       BufferedReader firstNum = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
       inputA = Double.parseDouble(firstNum.readLine());
    }
}
```

how can I test this method to get double?

```
public class CalcServiceTest {

    double inputA = 0.0;
    
    @Test
    @SneakyThrows(IOException.class)
    public void firstNumberTest() {
        System.out.println("Input first number");
        BufferedReader secondNum = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)); 
        inputA = Double.parseDouble(secondNum.readLine());
    }
}
```

test does not get input and pending
corrected the inaccuracies

Comment: `public void firstNumber)` - does it compile?

Comment: `CalcService calc = new CalcService();  ` - if you define this in a method, thehn it only has scope within that method.

Comment: Try this: https://junit-pioneer.org/docs/standard-input-output/

Comment: I’m so thoughtful I mixed up the test method...
but works both method from code and test method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These methods are not very suitable for testing, as they interact directly with user input through the console and depend on the external environment.
(Thanks [Rob Spoor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1180351/rob-spoor))

I create a simulation of user input and transfer it into methods. I do this using the class java.io.ByteArrayInputStream.

```
@Test
public void testFirstNumber() {
    CalcService calc = new CalcService();

    // Configure the input flow using ByteArrayInputStream
    String input = "10.0\n"; // user input
    InputStream in = new ByteArrayInputStream(input.getBytes());
    System.setIn(in);

    calc.firstNumber(); // called tested method

    // Check that the entered value is correct
    assertEquals(10.0, calc.getInputA(), 0.001);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can do all kinds of tricks to hack your tests to work but nothing changes the fact that the code is "untestable" because it is badly written.

Refer to [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID) principles, especially dependency inversion. Instead of writing your `CalcService` to explicitly depend on `System.in`, make it depend on a generig `Reader` that is provided to it by whoever creates the `CalcService`. Then in your unit tests pass a `Reader` with one that suits your test case.

[Change System.in and make Scanners use one ByteArrayInputStream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14918372/change-system-in-and-make-scanners-use-one-bytearrayinputstream)